# PowerShell script cannot open CSV/excel file when run from a Scheduler

Tags: excel, powershell, control-m

I am trying to run a Powershell Script which contain the below Snippet of code from (Control M -Scheduler)

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

 $workbook=$excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath,0,$false)
```

I am getting the below weird error

Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'Test_File.csv'. There are several possible reasons:

The file name or path does not exist.
 The file is being used by another program.
 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook."

With Same Id and Same environment when I tried to run from ISE, the code works like a charm
So No idea what is going on

Comment: Has Control M's service account permissions to access the file? If not sure, start a shell with runas and check it out, or use Procmon.

Comment: yes it does have the access.

Comment: does it work with Windows scheduler ?

Comment: Is the file already opened in Excel?

Comment: We have to use CTM , never tried windows  scheduler

Comment: @Theo No the file is not opened by any other  application

Comment: You **DO** quit Excel and release all used COM objects from memory after having finished with them do you?

Comment: yes. the same code is working for multiple run when submitted from Powershell ISE directly

Answer (score 0):

Here is what needs to be done:

1. Open cmd on the server.
2. Navigate to the script location.
3. Create folder using:

   ```
   mkdir C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
   ```
4. Rerun the job Control-M

You can read more about it at:
https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-73715